# Combining citations at some instance

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I use Jabref to manage my citations. Each entry has it own bibkey. There are some instance where I would like to cite 2 or more articles but I want them consolidated in one reference since there all talk about the same thing.

For instance in my text; `"... previous work involving MEAM[10]...."` and in the references [10] should look like this:

> `[10] M. I. Baskes, Phys. Rev. Lett. 59, 2666 (1987); M. I. Baskes, J. S. Nelson, and A. F. Wright, Phys. Rev. B 40, 6085 (1989); M. I. Baskes, Phys. Rev. B 46, 2727 (1992); M. I. Baskes, Mater. Chem. Phys. 50, 152 (1997).`

I do not want this: `"... previous work involving MEAM[10-13]..."`  where in the reference each article is cited as :

> `[10] M. I. Baskes, Phys. Rev. Lett. 59, 2666 (1987).`
>
> `[11] M. I. Baskes, J. S. Nelson, and A. F. Wright, Phys. Rev. B 40, 6085 (1989).`
>
> `[12] M. I. Baskes, Phys. Rev. B 46, 2727 (1992).`
>
> `[13] M. I. Baskes, Mater. Chem. Phys. 50, 152 (1997).`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a package just for physicists like you: [mciteplus](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mciteplus)

> mciteplus LaTeX package is an enhanced
>   reimplementation of Thorsten Ohl’s
>   mcite package which provides support
>   for the grouping of multiple citations
>   together as is often done in physics
>   journals

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried using the mciteplus pakage. From the documentation I had to add certain lines to my .bst file. After adding them I am getting an error that says that "Tex capacity exceeded Sorry...." Not sure what the error is but trying to use the original .bst file give the same error. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Works now. I do not know how Tex capacity exceeded came about but after some fiddling it is gone now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `revtex4-1` and write `\cite{refa,*refb,*refc}`.

Comment: This is for my thesis so I have created my own bst file because my adviser do not like the default format used by revtex.

Comment: In that case I would personally avoid using grouped citations in this way. It is usually mainly done to save some space, but in a thesis there shouldn't be such a stringent length limitation.