# How to cite a group of papers with the same citing number?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to cite 4 papers with different authors, titles and published in different years, that are related by the subject. I'm using JabRef to generate the BibTex file, and also the usual enviroment for bibliography: Cite package, etc. 
Maybe you could give a way to take or reorder my BibTex file or some tool in Jabref to do this.

I found an image that could show what I want...

[image: Group references like in [1] in the image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to associate more than one publication with a given call-out number (say, `[1]`)?

Comment: Yes, as [1] in image above, I would like to do that. I have the list of references in JabRef, is there some way to do this modifying something in JabRef?.

Comment: Nothing to do with JabRef, which just manages the citations. This looks like a physics/chemistry style 'multi-citation' which can be done in a few ways. To make the best suggestion, we'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your input. In particular, what's important here is your bibliography style and whether you are using `biblatex`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Ok with the JabRef. I don't have an imput 'cause I would like to know how to group, say Ref1 (title, author,...) and Ref2 (title, author,...) and give only one number to cite them. I'm using ieeetr style and I have a .bib file (I that was you meant with biblatex). Sorry I'm a bit new in latex. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [Combining citations at some instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15747/combining-citations-at-some-instance/15749), you are looks for the functionality of [`mciteplus`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mcieplus). This requires a suitable bibliography style and some slight modifications to standard input. As you are using `IEEEtran` as your bibliography style things are easy: there is an 'out of the box' style to work with `mciteplus` for this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Renchan2003,
  author  = {Renchan, E. D.},
  journal = {Proc. Inf. Conf. Computer-Aided Design},
  pages   = {123-126},
  title   = {{UBKSS}: realizable reduction in extracted PL circuits},
  year    = {2003},
}

@techreport{Shuangle2004,
  author      = {Shuangle, W.},
  institution = {National University, Department of Computer Science},
  pages       = {304-309},
  number      = {RN-CS-99-03},
  title       = {The high algorithm},
  year        = {2004},
}

@article{Wang2007,
  author  = {Wang, F. M.},
  journal = {IEEE Trans. Electron Devices},
  pages   = {304-309},
  title   = {Analysis and synthesis of on chip spiral inductors},
  volume  = {36},
  year    = {2007},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
% Turn on mciteplus sublists
\mciteSetSublistMode{s}
% Make the sublists simply create new paragraphs
\mciteSetSublistLabelBeginEnd{\par}{\relax}{\relax}
\mciteSetMidEndSepPunct
  {\ifmciteBstWouldAddEndPunct.\else\fi\space}
  {\ifmciteBstWouldAddEndPunct.\else\fi}
  {\relax}
\begin{document}
\cite{Renchan2003,*Wang2007,Shuangle2004}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranM}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've prefixed the 'subentry' citation with a star: that's required for `mciteplus` to know to combine entries. I've also set up the 'sublist' to simply print each entry on a new line.

If you want to use `natbib` along with `mciteplus` there is a `IEEEtranMN` style for that.

Comment: If you would rather use `biblatex` than 'traditional' BibTeX then the same effect is possible, but the interface is different. I can give an example of that too if required.

Comment: Now, what is necessary to do when I have already a .bib file? My bibliography file is included by \addscontentsline, then my reference file is added by \bibliography{Biblioteca.bib} (Biblioteca is jobname in your example). My question is: Can I apply your example to my case?. I other word, I could change only the bibliography style, add the package (and the next commands) and put * before the reference I want to "join" with the previous one?

Comment: @Resanrom Just a question of changing the appropriate `\bibliography` and `\cite` lines: there is nothing special about the `.bib` file here.

Answer (score 0):

In your jabref software, hold down the `Ctrl` key and left click on those two entries you want to extract their bibkey; when you selected them; right click over one of them and choose `Copy \cite{bibtexkey}`. Paste the key into somewhere you like to cite.

That's it. You will have a citation like the above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include more than one references and cite them by only one "citing number", like [1] in the reference part of the image, not citing [1] and[2] as [1,2].

Comment: @Resanrom I don't think it's a good idea to cite two different entries by only one number. Different entries should have different numbering.

Comment: @Entusiastic Student Yes, I know...but in this case I would like to...say, that the papers are about the same subject, I mean "if ypu wann to read some about this, you can read these papers"...and give only one citing number, because I have 5 papers, and dont wanna to have, say [25,26,27,28,29] this time.

Comment: @Resanrom in case of [25,26,27,28,29], the biblatex will show [25-29]. You normally don't need to make a new citation style.

Comment: @Entusiastic Student Yes, my mistake. I meant, say [25,32,78,etc]...my idea was to include those reference inside only one, first to "reduce" the numbers in my bibliography, and second to group (which is the stronger reason) some extra references at the end, that could give to the reader a further and connected information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `natbib` package, you can use the following command

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
```